# pass signal through hazelcast

Tags: java, message-queue, hazelcast

I put message to hazelcast queue like this:

```
hazelcastInstance.getQueue(LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME).add(Void.TYPE);
```

In another side I have registered queue listener:

```
hazelcastInstance.getQueue(LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME).addItemListener(new ItemListener<Void>() {
   @Override
   public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<Void> item) {
     LOGGER.info("Logout all user signal received");
     logoutAllUsers();
   }

   @Override
   public void itemRemoved(ItemEvent<Void> item) {
          //
   }
 }, false);
}
```

It doesn't compile.

```
> Error:(36, 50) java: D:\...\LogoutServiceImpl.java:36:
> addItemListener(com.hazelcast.core.ItemListener<java.lang.Object>,boolean)
> in com.hazelcast.core.ICollection<java.lang.Object> cannot be applied
> to (<anonymous
> com.hazelcast.core.ItemListener<java.lang.Void>>,boolean)
```

I just want to pass signal from one place to another without value.

How does hazelcast suppose to do this?

P.S.

I use java 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was related with

```
hazelcastInstance.getQueue(LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME)
```

returns `IQueue<Object>`.  If cast it to `IQueue<Void>` - all works properly

Comment: `hazelcastInstance.<Void>getQueue(LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME)` is better.